# Android Build error

Tags: android, push-notification

I am doing ionic push notification using FCM during build apk build error came.please help me to solve this issue.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-service
s-gcm:9.8+.
     Versions that do not match:
         9.4.0
         9.2.1
         9.2.0
         9.0.2
         9.0.1
         + 5 more
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm
/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm
/
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/ma
ven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
         file:/C:/Users/veeravel.p/android-sdks/extras/android/m2repository/com/
google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/C:/Users/veeravel.p/android-sdks/extras/android/m2repository/com/
google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
         file:/C:/Users/veeravel.p/android-sdks/extras/google/m2repository/com/g
oogle/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Could you add your build.gradle please?

Comment: Make sure you use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in your top-level build file `dependencies`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add that in your top-level build file :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    ...
}
```